# How to calculate the output image with the following kernel?

Tags: image-processing, filters, convolution

[image: scanned exercice]

What is the advantage of using this equation? I guess we may use Taylor series, but  I tried my best and could not get   the equation.

Comment: Welcome to SE.DSP. Generally, it is well-appreciated that one rewrites questions instead of doing a copy-paste of a scan. And personal thoughts are a plus

Comment: I see,it is the first time for me to do so. and I want to ask,what if the drawback of this way?

Comment: K is floor(N/2)

Comment: Homogeneity of the notations and searchability are better when typing: the search engine cannot find words or equations easily in images

Comment: how did you define the leftmost point and the rightmost one？a little confused

Comment: And，are there any potential problems when using this equation？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image is 2D, the kernel seems 1D. So let us double check: from (b), the output image is determined for each fixed $i$, and then only depends in $j$: Equation (1) only uses the second coordinate as the moving index.

So the kernel is effectively a $1\times N $ matrix. Its sum is $1$, and as $N$ is odd, you can interpret it as an equally-weighted moving average filter, applied along lines only. So it can behave like an horizontal motion blur (Question (a)).

The direct convolution requires $N-1$ adds, and one multiply (by $1/N$). Equation (1) tries to make it more efficient, both in terms of operations and calls to samples. It simply uses a recursive formulation for 1D moving average filters (a line of the image, here $x_j = I(.,j)$:

$$ \sum_{j=1}^N x_j = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} x_j - x_0 + x_N $$

I suspect that in your formula, $K$ should be defined as $2K+1=N$. There is consistent with $K=\mathrm{floor}(N/2)$ for $N$ odd.

In other words: instead of doing sums of pixels each time you go to the right, you can reuse previous computations. The novel mean $I_0(i,j)$ is the last mean $I_0(i,j-1)$  minus $1/N$ the leftmost sample (the one that just left the previous frame) plus $1/N$ the rightmost sample (the one that just arrived).

Almost nothing to do with Taylor. The advantages:

- a running buffer of $3$ values only is needed,
- its is independent of the kernel size,
- some computations can be saved if $N$ is relatively large (say $N\ge 5$).

Comment: K is floor(N/2)

Comment: what the disadvantage of this way?

Comment: how did you define the leftmost point and the rightmost one？a little confused